# При создании пользователя, игнорируется проверка

Tags: javascript, express

Пытаюсь реализовать проверку полей при регистрации пользователя с помощью миддлвейра express-validator.

Сам middleware:

```
const express = require('express')
const {check, checkSchema} = require('express-validator')
const emailPattern = /^(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/

const app = express()

app.post('/auth', async (req, res, next) => {
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        return next()

    }  try {
        // const {firstName, secondName, email, password} = req.body
        check('email')
        .matches(emailPattern)
        .withMessage("Неверный формат"),

        check('password')
        .isLength({min: 8})
        .withMessage("Минимальная длина пароля - 8 символов")
        next()

    } catch (e){
        res.status(500).json({message: "Что-то пошло не так"})
        throw new Error (e)
    }
})

module.exports = app
```

И роут к нему

```
const {Router} = require('express')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const auth = require('E:/client-system/server/middleware/AuthMiddleware')
const config = require('config')
const User = require('../models/User')

const router = Router()


    router.post('/register', auth, async (req, res) => {

    try{
        const {firstName, secondName, email, password} = req.body

        const candidate = await User.findOne({ email })

        if(candidate) {
            return res.status(400).json({message: "Такой пользователь уже существует"})
        }

        const hashPass = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12)
        const user = new User({
            firstName,
            secondName, 
            email, 
            password: hashPass
        })

        await user.save()

        res.status(201).json({message: "Пользователь создан"})

    } catch (e){
         res.status(500).json({message: "Что-то пошло не так"})
         throw new Error(e)
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

В Постман в body передаю json такого формата:

```
{
    "firstName": "regUser1",
    "secondName": "regUser1",
    "email": "registerUser1",
    "password": "registerUserPass"
}
```

Программа не видит ошибки несоответствия email и успешно создаёт пользователя в БД.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `try catch` разве для валидации, в каком случае мы получим ошибку? Почему запятая стоит после проверки `email`? Я все про первый кусок кода... Откуда вообще такая мода взялась не заканчивать выражение точкой с запятой, я что-то пропустил?

Comment: Виноват, ещё зелёный в этом плане

Comment: Да нет, сейчас во многих документациях по фрейм воркам такой "упрощенный" синтаксис, только раньше я этого не замечал. А про коду я не знаю, как должна работать функция `check` от `express-validator`, что возвращает. Потому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Если верить документации, то check возвращает цепочку валидаторов. Честно говоря, сам не до конца понимаю

Comment: Понятно, что `check` возвращает некий объект, который имеет метод `matches`, который возвращает тот же объект или другой имеющий метод `withMassage`.  И что? Как программа перейдет в секцию catch? Check выбросит исключение?

Comment: Я не знаю, под чем был, когда решил оборачивать эту структуру в try catch. Должно быть просто скопипастил с роута

Answer (score 0):

В общем, всё оказалось намного проще.

Достаточно было лишь применить метод test для моего emailPattern, и по итогу получить вот такую проверку:

```
const validEmail = emailPattern.test(email)

        if(!validEmail){
            return res.status(400).json({message: "Неверный формат"})
        }
```